# Apply KNN to a dataset contain binary (zero and one) ratings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, knn, recommendation-engine

I'm using the Python [Surprise library](https://surpriselib.com/) to train a KNN model based on a CSV file. The CSV file contains users, items, and ratings as usual.

In my case, ratings are **only zeros and ones** because I have only two possibilities either a user uses some item or not in the problem space. Still, I don't have zero ratings in my dataset. Hence the CSV files for train and test data are something like this with only rows with a rating number of 1:

```
user1, item1, 1
user1, item2, 1
user2, item1, 1
user2, item3, 1
user4, item4, 1
```

If I want to get a correct result from the KNN model, I have to add rows like `user1, item3, 0` to my dataset, but the problem is that because the dataset is sparse, the final dataset will become huge if I add zero rating rows to it and it is a time-consuming task.

Firstly, I opened CSV files for test and train datasets:

```
import pandas as pd
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import Reader
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = pd.read_csv('train.csv'), pd.read_csv('test.csv'])
train_data = Dataset.load_from_df(train[["user", "item", "rating"]], Reader(rating_scale=(0, 1)))
test_data = Dataset.load_from_df(test[["user", "item", "rating"]], Reader(rating_scale=(0, 1)))
train_set = train_data.build_full_trainset()
test_set = train_test_split(test_data, test_size=1.0)[1]
```

I found a solution to add zero rating rows to the DataFrame of the opened data, but I'm sure that there is a better solution:

```
train_set_filled = []
for u in train_set.all_users():
    user_items = {j for (j, _) in train_set.ur[u]}
    for i in train_set.all_items():
        if i not in user_items:
            train_set_filled += [(train_set.to_raw_uid(u), train_set.to_raw_iid(i), 0)]
        else:
            train_set_filled += [(train_set.to_raw_uid(u), train_set.to_raw_iid(i), 1)]
train_set = Dataset.load_from_df(pd.DataFrame(train_set_filled), Reader(rating_scale=(0, 1))).build_full_trainset()
```

Finally, I trained the model and tested my test data against it:

```
algo = train(train_set)
predictions = algo.test(test_set, verbose=False)
```

The Surprise library has different algorithms named KNNBasic, KNNWithZScore, KNNBaseline, SVD, SVDpp, NMF, SlopeOne, and CoClustering. My second question is, which of these algorithms best fits data with zero and one ratings?

Comment: there is no straight forward answer to that question, you should try them and choose the most appropriate model for your data based on a validation set